# Using gson with kotlin.stdlib.Result

Tags: kotlin, generics, gson

I'm trying to parse json into an object which is a [Result](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-result/) type and it works however it throws an exception when I try to access the actual object

This is what my code looks like:

```
val resultsType = object : TypeToken<Result<SomeObject>>() {}.type
val response = gson.fromJson<Result<SomeObject>>(jsonString, resultsType)
assertTrue(response.isSuccess) // it works
response.onSuccess { // throws exception
       println(it) 
}
```

This is the exception is get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap incompatible with com.abc.SomeObject
```

The strange thing is if I debug and inspect the response in IDE it has all the values. So, I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Your `Gson` instance lacks `Result` deserializer support.

Comment: So, I need to manually configure it to parse it correctly?

Comment: Yes, Gson is a Java-6-based library with very _limited_ support of its basic types (Java 8 types are not even included and are supposed to be added manually if necessary; same goes for whatever other types like Kotlin `Result`). Other types must be added manually by implementing type adapter factories (the most flexible and reliable solution), and their respective serializers and deserializers.

Answer (score 1):

`kotlin.Result` is `@JvmInline value class`, so creating a Gson serializer will be very non-trivial. The best option for data binding such classes is to use [kotlinx-serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization).